# C#/WPF hotkey on a not focused form (like launchy)

Tags: c#, wpf, hotkeys

Is it possible to catch a hotkey (eg. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) from a not focused form, to make it appear whenever someone uses this specific hotkey ; And without having to register this hotkey on the registry.
A similar event can be noticed in the application "Launchy".

Thank you

---

Language : C# (WPF) //
OS : Windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call the [`RegisterHotKey` API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
[Here](http://outcoldman.ru/en/blog/show/240) is a WPF wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm using .net 3.5 => "System.Diagnostics.Contracts" is not available

Comment: @Ars: You can replace those lines with `if` checks and exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to do that in the Active form by handling KeyDown Event